# C programming, How to edit/update a csv file

Tags: c, csv

I am doing a project which involves using .csv files handling in c. I have been bothered with this question and can't find a solution, I want to know how to edit/ update my csv file.

My csv file is something like:
Username, Pin, Balance

Right now I am able to get the contents of the csv file, but I am struggling on how to update the contents.
I want to make it so that a username can change its pin, so basically changing the value at pin to be something else.

After reading the comments I have tried the replacing method, it goes like this.

```
void change_pin(char *C){
    char line[200];
    char user[50];
    char date[50];

    char action[50];
    char user_n[50];
    char date_n[50];
    char action_n[50];
    FILE *str = fopen("Example.csv", "r+");
    FILE *new = fopen("new.csv", "w");
    if (str == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file");
        fclose(str);}
    if (new == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file");
        fclose(new);}

    while(fgets(line, 200, str)){
        char *token;
        token = strtok(line, ",");
        while (token != NULL){
            if (strcmp(token, C) == 0){
                strcpy(user, token);
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                strcpy(date, token);
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                strcpy(action, token);
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                strcpy(date, C);
                fprintf(new, "%s,%s,%s\n", user, date, action);
            }
            else{
                strcpy(user_n, token);
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                strcpy(date_n, token);
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                strcpy(action_n, token);
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                fprintf(new, "%s,%s,%s\n", user_n, date_n, action_n);
            }
    }
}
    remove("Example.csv");
    rename("new.csv", "Example.csv");
    fclose(str);
    fclose(new);
}
```

The strcpy (date, C) is just for testing
This works!, but the problem is it doesn't work the second time, I don't know why, when I want to do it the second time it gives a error.

I got it to work now just by removing the '\n' in fprintf. Thank you everyone for helping me out

Comment: `FILE *file = fopen("file.csv", "a); fprintf(file, "%s %d %s\n", username, pin, balance);` will do the job, `"a"` stands for append, if you want to replace the contents use `"w"`. If you want to open the file for "read" and "append"  at the same time use "a+".

Comment: @DavidRanieri Editing a CSV file inline is usually not really convenient. The usual way is to write a new file, writing all unmodified lines straight into a new file, but replacing the modified line with the new version. Then finally you delete the old file and rename the new file to the old.

Comment: @Cheatah yes, thats true, OP, if you are done reading the file (i.e. storing the contents of the file into an array) then there is no problem with "a+", otherwise you need to use Cheatah's approach (do not mix read / write ops).

Comment: @DavidRanieri, I have posted a draft for the method that you have suggested, it would be a huge help if you can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: @Cheatah, I have posted a draft for the method that you have suggested, it would be a huge help if you can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: You should close both files before removing the old one and renaming the new one. But you should also really add error checking. Never delete the old file until you know the new file was written correctly.

Comment: @Cheatah, It still give a error -Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV). How do I say this, My code works the first time it is run, but if I want to edit the file again it doesn't work. This is in different runs, Im sorry if my explanation is bad because im new to programming and I do not know how to address it.